# Why am I having trouble with getline()? "No instance of overloaded functions matches the argument list" and "data is ambiguous"

Tags: c++, cin, getline, ambiguous

I've used this exact function before, but simply copy and pasting it to another file has caused it to stop working. The only change is that i added "using namespace std".

In my "ReadData()" function, I'm getting an error on getline(cin, data) that no instance of overloaded functions matches the argument list. Also, I'm getting an error on "data" in the call, saying "data is ambiguous."

The function is supposed to read data from a text file and store the line of text in data for further processing. This function has worked exactly how it is so I'm just not sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "NvraArray.h"
#include "NvraRecord.h"

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

// Globals
string data; // Stores the line that getline is at
vector<string> rows; // Stores the rows of data
vector<int> recordNumbersSeen; // Holds records numbers that have been checked
string strWords[24]; // Holds the individual columns of data for processing
int rowCounter = 0; // Counts the rows of data coming in

// Prototypes
// Reads the data from cin into the "rows" vector
void ReadData();
// Checks the current row against the list of records already seen
bool isDuplicate(int recordID);
// Checks the current row for invalid data
bool isValidData();
// Splits the row into an array to process
void SplitRowIntoArray(std::string row);

int main(){

    // For testing purposes
    srand(time(NULL));

    NvraArray array;
    NvraRecord record;



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void ReadData(){
    while(getline(cin,data)){

        // if on the first row, do nothing and skip to the next.
        if(rowCounter != 0){

            rows.push_back(data);
        }else{
            rowCounter++;   
        }
    }
    rowCounter = 0;
}
```

Comment: Totally off topic, but I shudder to see global variables abused this way. Please stop that.

Comment: If you alter the title to describe the problem (perhaps by quoting the error) then the title will be more useful

Comment: Well Instead of blasting my style, care to elaborate so I may understand why this is an error?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Nobody knows what is NvraRecord or NvraArray. Also copy and paste entire error messages verbatim instead of providing an executive summary.

Comment: Why do you use an array for `string` but a `vector` for integers?  You can use a `vector` for strings also.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews We're doing projects that are building on the one before it. The first project I did, I made the mistake you are referring to and I just don't want to mess with something that is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a prime example of why you *shouldn't* use `using namespace std;`.  You have a name conflict: `string data` is conflicting with [`std::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data).

If this is not enough to convince you, check out [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/symbol_index) list of some of the other names in the `std` namespace.  If you use `using namespace std;`, *any* of these names could cause a collision if you happen to include the right headers.

Answer (score 5):

You run into a conflict with the [`std::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data) function template that was introduced with C++17. Apparently one of the standard library headers you're including pulls in an include to `iterator`.

Renaming your global variable to something other than `data` should fix the issue.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As a sibling to the non-member `begin`/`end` functions, it's really the only name that makes sense. I agree that the resulting error is nasty, but I suspect having given it a different name would be an even bigger nuisance in practice.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Perhaps. I mean I can see where it came from but ugh

Comment: @Fureeish Actually it comes from `<iterator>` but, as always, your particular stdlib implementation may wind up including that via other headers. Results will vary across platforms.

Comment: What I meant by that is by including `<string>` it is guaranteed that `<iterator>` is also included. I worded my first comment pretty poorly